# Multiple na.strings in read.table() function in R

Tags: r, na, read.table

I have a square table and it has two na.strings (e.g. "A" and "B") that I need to turn into NA. So far I can turn either one of those into NA but not both. How should I do this? Can I use a function in that argument? If yes, what function should I use? I tried like (`na.strings = "A" | "B"`) and (`na.strings = "A | B"`) but it does not work. My code is as follows:

```
loadfile<-read.table("test.csv", header=T, sep=",", na.strings="A | B")
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`na.strings` takes a character vector, so...

```
loadfile <- read.table( "test.csv" , header = TRUE ,
                         sep="," ,
                         na.strings = c("A" , "B" ) )
```

From the helpfile:

> na.strings: a character vector of strings which are to be interpreted as NA values

Comment: @Jilber lol! That's happened to me more than a few times. Us `R` tag junkies are a dedicated lot. :-)